# Taking user input and assigning it to hash map in different class

Tags: java

I'm trying to take user input and assign it to a hashmap in a different class. My intent was to declare a map in the main class and store the values in said map and then assign the data that was collected in the main class map to the map in the other class through a constructor. The map is structured `<string, integer>` and the goal is to print both values instead of just one. How do I go about this? I'm getting this specific error with my code so far where I'm putting the values into the map (oldVal)

> Error: required: java.lang.string found: java.lang.integer

**Here's my code:

Main class -**

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class Main{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        int choice;
        final int MAX = 999999999;
        boolean loopAgain = true;
        HashMap<String, Integer> mapRatings = new HashMap<>();

           System.out.println("Enter movie rating (PG OR NC): ");
           String rating = input.nextLine();

           System.out.println("Enter the rating age (13 OR 17): ");
           Integer ratingId = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());

           String oldVal = mapRatings.put(rating, ratingId);
    }
}
```

**Movie class:**

```
import java.util.*;

public class Movie {
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String description;
    private String[] genre;
    private String[] actors;
    private String[] language;
    private String countryOfOrigin;
    private Map<String, Integer> ratings;    

//Constructor
    public Movie(String id, String name, String description, String[] genre, String[] actors, String[] language, String countryOfOrigin, Map<String, Integer> ratings){
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
        this.genre = genre;
        this.actors = actors;
        this.language = language;
        this.countryOfOrigin = countryOfOrigin;
        this.ratings = ratings;
    }

 public void setRatings(Map<String, Integer> ratings){
        this.ratings = ratings;
    }
}
```

Comment: `mapRatings.put(rating, ratingId);` this code returns Integer and you try to equal Integer with String. Why are you doing that?

Comment: @Matrix4290 Ahh I see it now thank you! `mapRatings.put(rating, ratingId);` would fix this problem, correct?

Comment: @SharleneRoberts - I recommend you not to focus on just the fix; rather, it's important that you understand the problem, concept etc. which will help you avoid similar problems in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Check the [Map documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#put-K-V-) given below:

```
V put​(K key, V value)
```

**Parameters:**

```
key - key with which the specified value is to be associated
value - value to be associated with the specified key
```

i.e. the return type should match with the type of `value`. In your case, your value is of type, `int` and therefore you should write

```
int oldVal = mapRatings.put(rating, ratingId);
```

Comment: If you'd like to see `rating` not `ratingId` in `oldVal`. Key and Value types have to change in hash map defination `HashMap<Integer, String> mapRatings = new HashMap<>();`